# How to use VS 2008 Shell to create SQL Server .net Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to learn to create .net stored procedures, triggers, etc. using SQL Server 2008 Developer. I'm guessing my edition of Visual Studio 2008 Shell was installed with SS. At any rate, when I open visual studio and try to create a new project, all that is available is Business Intelligence Project and Other Project types. Other project types only lists Visual Studio Solutions.

Question: Is Visual Studio 2008 Shell appropriate for this or do I need a full-blown version? If I need the real thing, will VS 2010 Express work and if so, do I need to uninstall VS 2008 Shell first?
I have been searching for days for a solution to this. Any ideas any one?

Comment: a basic text editor is all that is required to create stored procedures...

Comment: Hi Mitch and thanks for your response. I'm trying to learn to create the .net procedures, so I'm following instructions from a book. Supposedly when I finish the exercise there will be a flash of lightening and I'll be proclaimed a bona fide DEVELOPER! Treat me as someone who doesn't know much about what he's doing, cuz I don't. I do have to maintain some very complex scripts written against some very weird tables, so I'm compelled to learn as much as I can just to keep my head above water. What's up with VS 2008 Shell? Does it only come with BI projects? Should I trash it and install Express?

Comment: Hi @JoeDeal, did you have any luck with VS 2010 Express?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few gremlins regarding the order in which these various components (and versions of) are installed.

If you didn't previously have Visual Studio installed, the BI Dev Studio installation will install a VS shell called Visual Studio Premier Partner Edition.

From this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/bbd76eae-637c-421b-8222-44b253760d93/):

> You should make sure that Visual Studio is still installed. If you
>   didn't previously have VS installed, the BI Dev Studio installation
>   will install a VS shell called Visual Studio Premier Partner Edition.
>   Look in Add or Remove Programs for an entry like this. If you don't
>   find any entry for Visual Studio go to the location for SQL Server
>   setup and run .\Tools\Setup\vs_setup.exe. This will install the VS
>   Shell. After this is installed repair the BI Studio installation by
>   running the following from the command line from the .\Tools
>   directory: start /wait setup.exe /qb
>   REINSTALL=SQL_WarehouseDevWorkbench REINSTALLMODE=OMUS

Personally, I'd first try uninstalling the BIDS Shell version, and then installing Express (following above instructions if the extra project types don't appear).